# How to give a score if the element is present in the array in elastic search?

Tags: arrays, list, elasticsearch

```
"functions": [{
      "script_score": {
        "script": "(doc['content.acknowledgement'].value) ? ((doc['content.acknowledgementUsers'].values.contains(24)) ? 0 : 1 ) : 0"
      }
    }
  ],
  "score_mode": "sum"
```

This is the syntax i have so far. I'm trying to give a score based on these conditions.
If the users is in `acknowledgementUsers` give a score of `0` else give a score of `1`.

For some reason everytime the script is giving me score of 0. I'm using `elastic search 5.2`

Can some one please help me with this?

Comment: What are the values of `'content.acknowledgementUsers`?

Comment: 'content.acknowledgementUsers' is a list of integers.

Comment: Can you post your mapping?

Comment: `"content": {
            "properties": {
              "acknowledgement": {
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "acknowledgementUsers": {
                "type": "long"
              }}} `